# Issue with scale module d3 on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

Having this method on my react component

```
setForeground(context) {
     var color = d3.scale.ordinal()....
```

I allways get this error message

```
"export 'scale' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'
```

I'm currently importing all the d3 modules as I see on some examples.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

Looks that I'm not calling it properly, I have read that there must be some issues regarding d3 versions, but I have checked that I'm working with the last one..

Comment: It is `d3.scaleOrdinal()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using D3.js V4 or V5, there were introduced some breaking changes which are described in full in the [change log](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#scales-d3-scale). In particular, all the `d3.scale.xyz` functions were renamed to `d3.scaleXyz`, so `d3.scale.ordinal` is now `d3.scaleOrdinal`.

Comment: Absolutely true, d3.scaleOrdinal is the right way.
Thanks